# passing events to highest z-index minus one item for canvas on top of jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg

I'm trying to build a web app where a user can identify the columns used as a foreign key to join two tables. As an example, the user is presented with a list of columns in two tables and draws a line from column A on one side to column B on the other side.

The way I've coded it so far is to use two jQuery UI sortable (user drag and drop) lists (unordered list in HTML). What I wanted to do next is put a canvas over the front of the whole page and whenever I want to join two cells, I would draw an SVG bezier curve on the canvas.

The issue that I run into is handling events. Since the canvas is on top, it catches all of the mouse events. I found an SO answer that discussed attaching an event listener and passing events to a canvas if the canvas is behind your other controls, however I have the reverse situation. I want clicks to pass through the canvas to the jQuery UI control. Is there an easy way to identify which DOM object should receive the click? I found a function that would return the highest item in the z-plane with the same coordinates as the mouse click, however the canvas is blocking the way. It's like I need to ignore it.

From a more general point of view, my approach will probably work, however should I be mixing things like jQuery UI and canvases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pointer-events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property to make the canvas pass though mouse clicks. `pointer-events="none"` should do it.